# Putting crayons in an oven

Tags: kashrut-kosher, art, children

There is a children's craft activity involving melting crayons (based on paraffin wax) onto a shaped-mold in an oven. It has not been possible to get any information about what the crayons are made of, in particular the colour pigments that have been used i.e. whether they could derive from non-kosher sources.

Are there any concerns for the kashrut status of the oven that could be a problem if it indeed turns out that there are some non-kosher ingredients in the crayons, despite crayons not being edible?

Comment: Any ≤5-year-old I know would disagree with you regarding crayons' being edible...

Comment: Could there be a tzad to be lenient because the crayons are Nosein Tam L'Phgam?

Comment: @PloniAlmoni please translate the term at the end of your comment. Perhaps, in addition to translating, summarize the importance / relevance of this principle as it applies to this question.